# SoundManager2 AutoPlay loads file twice

Tags: jquery, soundmanager2

I have to include an audio file, which automatically plays and can be paused and played again by buttons. The pausing and playing works, however it seems, that the file is loaded twice and I can't find the problem. When I pause, the sound volume just goes down and if I press the play button, one "layer" continues playing, where I paused it, the other just keeps on playing... This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#play').hide();
  soundManager.setup({
    debugMode: false,
    onready: function () {
      soundManager.createSound({
        id: 'music',
        url: 'up/files/file.mp3',
        autoPlay: true,
        autoLoad: false
      })
    }
  });

  $('#play').bind('click', function() {
    var sound = soundManager.getSoundById('music');
    sound.play();
    $('#pause').show();
    $('#play').hide();
  });

  $('#pause').bind('click', function() {
    var sound = soundManager.getSoundById('music');
    sound.pause();
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
  });
});
```

**Edit**

As Alex Morrise said, this seems to be a bug in the soundmanager2.js file. I now fixed this by providing a path to the swf-files and setting the `preferFlash` option to `true`, like so:

```
soundManager.setup({
  url: 'path/to/swf-files',
  preferFlash: true,
  debugMode: false,
  onready: function () {
    soundManager.createSound({
      id: 'music',
      url: 'up/files/file.mp3',
      autoPlay: true,
      autoLoad: false
    })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in SoundManager. The `soundManager.createSound` method runs a `_setup_html5` method. If you've set `autoPlay`, that `_setup_html5` method calls a `load` function, which loads the sound.

However, in the `load` function, it checks to see if your browser supports HTML5. If it does, it again calls `_setup_html5`, which calls `load` the second time.

Do you follow?

Here's a sampling of the code:

```
this._setup_html5 = function(oOptions) {
    //...
    if (instanceOptions.autoLoad || instanceOptions.autoPlay) {
        s.load();
    }
    //...
}

this.load = function(oOptions) {
    //...
    if (html5OK(instanceOptions)) {
        oSound = s._setup_html5(instanceOptions);
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it... I'm gonna see, if I can fix that... thanks for your answer for now :)

Comment: Alright, I couldn't find how to fix it in the Soundmanager2.js itself (and frankly I'm glad, I don't wanna be messing around in those files...). I now fixed it by writing `url: 'path/to/swf-files'` and `preferFlash: true` in the setup part of the code... I'm gonna edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue recently.

I noticed the message from Soundmanager2 debug output:

Cloning Audio() for instance #

The SoundObject cloning was not really useful for my purposes.

I edited the soundmanager2.js file. 
Search for the output string:

> Cloning Audio()

around line 2021:

```
if (s.instanceCount < 2) {

        // HTML5 single-instance case

        start_html5_timer();

        a = s._setup_html5();

        s.setPosition(s._iO.position);

        a.play();

      } /*else {

        // HTML5 multi-shot case

        sm2._wD(s.id + ': Cloning Audio() for instance #' + s.instanceCount + '...');

        audioClone = new Audio(s._iO.url);

        onended = function() {

        ...
```

Commenting out the entire **else** option, the *html5 support* of soundmanager2 makes use of only one SMSound object.

It still allows to autoplay a element by creating a new object by using again the method

[soundManager.createSound()](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#smsound-createsound)